# Ratio and Proportions Question

Tags: ratio

Can someone please answer this with proper explanation.

At sahara shopping centre, a person can purchase as much articles at a time as his or her age that is a person of a years age can purchase only n similar articles at a time .Amisha is younger to her elder brother who has just entered into his twenties. One day Amisha went to the Sahara Shopping centre, she purchased same toffees at a particular rate on the ground floor. But when she reached on third floor she found that she could purchase double the no. of toffees with the same amount as she had spent on the ground floor. Also to purchase the same no. of toffees on the third floor she had to spend Rs. 2 less than that of on the first floor. How many toffees did she buy?

Comment: This is hard to follow, and it doesn't appear that enough information has been given.  If I understand the rules (unlikely) then it's possible that $A$ bought one on the ground floor and two on the next, or two on the ground floor and four on the next.  Why not?  Do purchases on different levels count as "at a time" or not?   As I read it, all we know is that the toffees got cheaper on the upper floor.

Comment: Well, I am confused too. Actually I posted this on behalf of a friend. This questions was part of a mock test and the answer there is 12.  But with no explanation.

Comment: $12$, huh.  So the theory is that she bought $4$ on the ground floor and $8$ on the upper floor.  But I don't even see a way to reverse engineer that solution.  I think a lot of information has been left off.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Rupees      per rupees
```

Ground   X     x       Y      = XY

Third    X     x       2Y     = 2XY
|
|-->  X/2    x       2Y     = XY

```
   X - X/2 = 2 => |X = 4|
```

If the X=4 then multiple of 4 must be obtain from option , which gives the no. Of toffes did she get at last. And multiple of 4 is 12.

So the answer is 12, even though data is insufficient for value Y in it.